# Grow individual drive size in RAID5 array

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, mdadm, raid5

My array is built of 3 hard drive of 2TB, I have 2 more free space and I would love to start to grow my array with 4TB hard drives, if I start to put 2 4TB hard drives and eventualy replace the 2TB hard drives and grow the arry too!

Is it possible?

I'm using mdadm on a Ubuntu server 14.04!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, and as supported by [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250086/raid-mdadm-what-happens-if-drives-are-mismatched-in-size) article, you can setup a RAID array of different size disks, but the array will end up sized as *Number of Disks* * *Smallest Disk*.

> **Can I create an md(4) RAID array out of block devices of unequal size?**
>   Yes, but the RAID array will have the size of the smallest block device (plus some overheads for its own housekeeping). If device sizes aren't within 1% of each other, you get a warning.

This concept also applies to hardware RAID controllers like HP's SmartArray line.

The article referened above shows you how to test the theory by creating dummy devices and then layering `md` devices on top.

Comment: This is, in fact, one of the mentioned methods for expanding an array, see the [Expanding a partiton](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Growing) section of the mdadm wiki. Just keep in mind for most of these steps a full backup of the RAID is best, as the RAID is vulnerable during resyncing.

Answer (score -1):

No. In a raid, every member drive must be the same size, it is unavoidable. Otherwise, where could be mapped the upper 2TB of your new drives?

But, what you can do:

1. Partition your new drives to have two-two 2TB partitions,
2. Grow your old array to include the lower 2-2 TB partitions from your disks (`mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices=5`)
3. And finally, you will have 2-2 free TBs on your new disks.

It will be sometimes a little bit uncommon configuration, but it will work.

Comment: Oh, I really love your idea! I future, if we finish to have 6TB drives, I'll do the same, make 3 partitions of 2TB and get 3 more drives in the array! ;) Thanks!

Comment: @TheBuzzer67 This wasn't what I wrote. Maybe try it again.